# Render as PDF on a public site page

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, pdf

I'm developing a visualforce page that is supposed to be rendered as PDF. This page is to be accessed from a public URL. The page has two components. Although I'm facing some problems. if I fill in the parameter renderAs = pdf the page is rendered as a blank page but only in the public url. Example:
orgInstance/apex/myPage -> ok
publicSite/myPage -> blank page

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a permissions issue...happens to us all the time.

You have to make sure the public site "profile" permissions are allowed to access the page, the class, and all the objects it needs.

In the site settings click on the "Public Access Settings"

see this screenshot:[image]

Comment: That's what I though too, but, if I remove the tag renderAs='pdf' it works just fine...

Comment: Hmm maybe post some of the code includint the controller code?  tough to say without knowning more details.  I know pdfs do work publically, we are using that for a number of clients

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. That was related with an issue related to a StaticResource. Solved.

Comment: glad to hear it!  cheers

Comment: @PedroRibeiro Maybe you can explain what was going wrong in an answer so that people with a similar problem in the future are helped with your experience ?

Comment: @PedroRibeiro can you please add more info on what was the issue?